# Cisco RV032G port forwarding

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward port 22 from outside to a raspberry but I can't get it to work.

I setup the port forward and configured an access rule.

[Screenshots of the configuration are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVbN5.jpg)

[and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag1RW.jpg)

Is there anything else I have to configure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to configure it on the Setup>UPnP page too.

What you configured is the firewall rule, not the forward itself.

Comment: mhh.. I've also tried this before, I added it again but without success, I added the screenshot

Comment: At service option (just like in your screenshot) select all traffic instead of DNS. Did you configure it also in the forwarding tab ?

Comment: yea it was just there in the mask, I added SSH as a service ( port 22 ) and added it to the list.